# Iframe not loading complete contenty of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using an Iframe to to display the web browser of several satellite receivers in my webpage. However it does not load the page in its entirety. The background shows up but I am not able to see the login and password tabs . It looks like the iframe is blocking some scripts from running or something as when I open the webpage in a normal browser I see the login screen after a few seconds delay.

Here is the code that does not work

```
 <iframe id= "lrx09web" name= "lrx09web" width ="100%" height ="100%"
   src="http://192.168.10.109/" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups
   allow-forms allow-same-origin" scrolling ="yes"></iframe>
```

Please help

Comment: You're sandboxing it, so you are imposing some limitations. We can't tell which of the limitations is stopping your code from running because you've given us a vague description of what the code does instead of a relevant test case. http://sscce.org/

Comment: no I tried sanboxing because it did not work.. I have tried removing it and it does not work as well.. I do not need the sandbox

Comment: We still can't tell what is wrong with the vaguely described code we can't see. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is that I cannot give show it on the forum as the iframe source is only available locally in our internal network.. It looks like the iframe is stopping some javascript code to run. is there some way of stopping this.

Comment: "The problem is that I cannot give show it on the forum as the iframe source is only available locally in our internal network" — That does not prevent you from showing us a reduced test case. It just means you actually have to build the reduced test case.

Comment: how can I go about doing that

Comment: It looks like a page on load function that is not getting triggered when the source is to be displayed inside an iframe but runs properly in a browser. how can I get all JavaScript events to execute inside an iframe.